# How do I resolve error 10013 in Django development?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django by following the "Writing your first Django app, part 1" tutorial on the Django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/.
Everything works fine until I run `"python manage.py runserver"` in my command prompt. I get an error that says:

`Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`

I have tried using Windows PowerShell as well as a command prompt window to execute the following codes (all of which yield the same error):

`python manage.py runserver", "python manage.py runserver 8000", "python manage.py runserver 8080.`

Comment: Did you try running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I ran Windows PowerShell as administrator, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your pc using those ports 8000 and 8080. try to use a different port (eg.7000) and in my case, a simple restart pc worked perfectly. So if you restart your pc and then start your local server, I think it will work fine.